# Django - Taking value from POST request

Tags: python, django, post, request

I have a list of zones, identified by id (integer).
How can I get the zone that generated the post request?

**manual.html**

```
{% if zone_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for z in zone_list %}
            <b><p>{{z.name}}</p></b>
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" name="{{z.id}}" value="ON"/>
                <input type="submit" name="{{z.id}}" value="OFF"/><br>
                <br>
                <label>Tiempo</label>:
                <input type="integerfield" name="Tiempo">
                <input type="submit" name="{{z.id}}" value="Start">
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

In the views.py I have to change the 1 for something that dynamically represents the zone

**views.py**

```
def manual(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('1'):
        z = Zone.objects.get(id = 1)
        keyword = request.POST.get("1","")
        if keyword == "ON":
            #do something
        if keyword == "OFF":
            #do something
        if keyword == "Start":
            #do something
    zone_list = Zone.objects.all()
    context = {'zone_list':zone_list}
    return render(request, 'irrigation_controller/manual.html', context)
```

Comment: Create a [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) for a single zone and then use [modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) to create a set of forms. Then you can iterate on this form in your views and get value one by one

Comment: Or you can add a hidden input field that contains the zone's ID and then pull that out of `request.POST`.

Comment: @themanatuf Thanks for the help, I solved the problem using a hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. As themanatuf said, I used a hidden input field with the zone_id.

**manual.html**

```
{% if zone_list %}
    {% for z in zone_list %}
        <b><p>{{z.name}}</p></b>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="zone_id" value="{{z.id}}">
            <input type="submit" name="order" value="ON"/>
            <input type="submit" name="order" value="OFF"/><br>
            <br>
            <label>Tiempo</label>:
            <input type="integerfield" name="Tiempo">
            <input type="submit" name="order" value="Start">
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And in the view I read the zone_id and the order.

**views.py**

```
def manual(request):
if request.POST.has_key('zone_id'):
    z = Zone.objects.get(id = request.POST.get("zone_id",""))
    keyword = request.POST.get("order","")
    if keyword == "ON":
        z.irrigation_on()
    if keyword == "OFF":
        z.irrigation_off()
    if keyword == "Start":
        tiempo = request.POST['Tiempo']
        tiempo = float(tiempo)
        irrigation_time.delay(z.id, tiempo)
zone_list = Zone.objects.all()
context = {'zone_list':zone_list}
return render(request, 'irrigation_controller/manual.html', context)
```